# How do I remove weight from weight painting?

Tags: weight-painting

I am trying to remove some weight. I left click to add it, but I cannot figure out how to remove it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/tools.html#brush) on  blend mode:

Subtract: In this blend mode the specified weight is subtracted from the vertex weights. The strength determines which fraction of the weight gets removed per stroke. However the brush will not paint weight values below 0.0.

Lighten: In this blend mode the specified weight value is interpreted as the target weight very similar to the Mix Blend mode. But only weights below the target weight are affected. Weights above the target weight remain unchanged.

Blur: tries to smooth out the weighting of adjacent vertices. In this mode the Weight Value is ignored. The strength defines how effectively the blur is applied.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can enter edit mode, select the part(s) of the mesh where you need the weight changed (you can press <kbd>C</kbd> and also paint select) and in the *Data* panel (the button with the triangle) in the *Properties* context under *Vertex Groups*, set the weight slider to 0 and press *Assign*.

Answer (score 5):

Paint zero weight to effectively remove it (zero weight has no effect)
If you want to remove the vertex from the group you can run the "Clean" tool, or manually select and remove the vertices from the group.

See: Weight Paint Mode -> 3D View Header -> Weights -> Clean

Comment: what i "`the "clean" tool`" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can erase with draw brush. Change the weight parameter.

- 0.0: Deep eraser
- 0.3: Shallow eraser
- 0.7: Shallow brush
- 1.0: Deep brush

*Precautions:
Weight paint does not wet only vertex. Clicking on the vertex makes it dark.
Mirror side is not wet.
Weight values is recorded on the vertex data of the target mesh.
Vertex data is made only of the number of bones. When is it? Setting armature to parent. (with Automatic weight or with Empty group)

Please select together the target mesh and the bones in the order goes to the weight painting mode.
Operation: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> Selection of the bones. can be released by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Double Click</kbd>. This operation looks confusing.
When you paint the weight value is easy to understand and see while switching the object mode and weight painting mode in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.